# Datediff pivot by day and employee

Tags: sql, pivot, datediff

I use the following query to try and pull how much time our employees spent on each task...

```
select userid, workclassid,
convert(varchar(6), datediff(second,min(whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime), max(whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime))/3600) + ':' +
Right ('0' + convert(varchar(2), (datediff(second,min(whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime), max(whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime)) % 3600)/60),2) + ':' +
Right ('0' + convert(varchar(2), datediff(second,min(whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime), max(whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime)) %60),2) as 'Picking Time'
from whsworkline
where WORKclosedUTCDATETIME> '5/29/2018' and workclosedutcdatetime < '5/31/2018'  and whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime > '1/1/2001'
Group by userid, workclassid
Order by userid
```

Resulting in the following data...

```
`userid workclassid Picking Time
    JIT 33:05:34
    SO PICK 0:00:00
    MM  8:56:44
alexander.  MM  0:00:00
alexander.  JIT 29:20:09
alteriq.jo  PA-STAGE    31:32:23
alteriq.jo  PO_REC  0:00:00
antione.po  MM  3:57:48
antione.po  JIT 2:57:24
brandon.fe  SO PICK 24:09:50
brandon.fe  MM  7:43:13
brandon.fe  JIT 0:40:14
carl.barto  JIT 30:40:34
carl.barto  PA-FINAL    19:19:39
carl.barto  PA-STAGE    1:13:51
carl.barto  MM  6:24:28
chris.gran  PACKING 0:08:44
chris.gran  STAGE   0:08:50
chris.thom  PA-STAGE    23:12:40
chris.thom  PA-FINAL    32:47:41
cynthia.yo  SO PICK 30:36:09
deauntrey.  MM  0:33:01
deauntrey.  FG  0:09:09
deshawn.wr  SO PICK 24:37:13
deshawn.wr  MM  27:35:29
deshawn.wr  JIT 3:09:15
Devron.gra  SO PICK 28:33:30
edward.coo  CycCnt  0:25:40
Elease.wil  SO PICK 27:46:23
everlena.h  SO PICK 31:20:36
Frankie.mo  PA-STAGE    33:10:26
frankie.mo  PO_REC  0:00:00
Frankie.mo  PA-FINAL    33:22:11
franklin.w  JIT 3:54:12
franklin.w  PA-STAGE    1:56:04
franklin.w  PA-FINAL    4:50:59
harry.gran  PA-STAGE    31:40:41
harry.gran  PA-FINAL    24:53:10
IT      35:52:37
jalisa.whi  SO PICK 31:24:26
james.smoa  SO PICK 31:18:40
jaquan.har  SO PICK 4:45:02
jermany.ca  CycCnt  24:05:26
john.dobso  CycCnt  2:15:52
johnny.bus  JIT 29:56:52
johnny.bus  MM  6:17:14
johnny.bus  PA-FINAL    0:09:20
johnny.bus  PA-STAGE    0:00:15
Josee.nett  SO PICK 28:45:47
Karen.holm  SO PICK 25:19:53
keandrea.m  SO PICK 30:44:53
lacannin.r  MM  0:03:02
lacannin.r  SO PICK 27:26:03
lenard.loa  SO PICK 2:50:01
lenard.loa  MM  28:30:14
lenard.loa  JIT 25:54:28
marquis.ma  SO PICK 30:55:29
marzetta.g  CycCnt  31:11:31
matthew.pa  SO PICK 31:19:35
michael.kn  PACKING 0:00:09
michael.kn  SO PICK 0:00:03
myeisha.mi  SO PICK 30:48:39
nathaniel.  MM  0:04:13
nathaniel.  SO PICK 2:55:35
odell.may   MM  26:12:37
odell.may   JIT 1:35:49
odell.may   SO PICK 24:16:35
oveta.solo  SO PICK 25:58:15
paige.walt  SO PICK 28:48:27
pamela.fen  SO PICK 0:00:00
picker.2    SO PICK 28:30:22
reatha.jen  SO PICK 30:10:21
reginald.b  CycCnt  32:27:43
Sandra.sco  SO PICK 25:51:30
Savannah.g  SO PICK 28:48:05
Sharyll.bl  CycCnt  30:49:02
sherman.wi  SO PICK 31:18:02
sherwin.jo  SO PICK 29:00:37
sherwin.jo  JIT 0:00:19
shydon.Alb  JIT 25:56:35
shydon.Alb  MM  28:33:42
stephen.br  SO PICK 28:44:30
tewon.thom  MM  0:00:00
theaurthus  JIT 1:22:08
todd.grant  SO PICK 6:55:53
tyrone.mou  SO PICK 28:36:53
willie.car  JIT 2:00:50
willie.car  MM  28:35:34
Willie.dav  SO PICK 6:55:38
zakira.wat  SO PICK 30:41:17
```

`

I am trying to solve for 3 different issues with this data.

1a) obviously this is for a 24 hour period and it shouldnt be possible to accumulate more than 24 hours on a single task, so Im sure there is something fundamentally wrong with my datediff section.

1b) Our employees jump between tasks all the time, which is the workclassid, so if Im calculating the datediff between the first and last timestamp of each class and theyve gone back and forth between work classes, the data will come out to more than 24 hours. I have tried to calculate that time by individual works within the classes then sum that data, with no success.

2) when I get that portion of the data figured out I need to be able to pivot the data so I can pull the totals by day for each employee. Something like this is what I am going for...

```
Employee    WorkClassID   Mon       Tues       Wed   ...
alexander.    mm        0:00:00   0:23:09   
alexander.    jit       29:20:09  0:00:00
alteriq.jo   pa-stage   31:32:23  0:01:23
```

and so on. (the data there for Tuesday is made up data since I have not found a way to pull one day correctly, I havent been able to pull the second.) but that is the way Im hopng to make everything look.

I have researched heavily the pivot function but I have not been able to get that to work and I dont know if thats because of my issues 1a and 1b or what. I tried to only post the portions that I could get to work at least partially but if anyone needs to see how I did the other portions I can certainly post those.

Also I tried creating a function for problem 2 however our database security prevents us from creating new functions currently. Thank you all for any help or direction. Take care.

Ok Jarl, here is the query I used (I only pulled the data for two shipments because Id run out of characters in my post otherwise)

```
select *
from whsworkline
where (shipmentid='SH-000146504' or shipmentid='SH-000144368')
order by workid, linenum
```

This is the resulting data...

```
WORKID  LINENUM WORKSTATUS  WORKTYPE    WMSLOCATIONID   ITEMID  INVENTDIMID QTYREMAIN   INVENTQTYREMAIN INVENTQTYWORK   UNITID  USERID  WORKSTOP    INVENTTRANSID   WORKTYPECUSTOMCODE  ASKFORNEWLICENSEPLATE   MANDATORY   WORKTEMPLATELINERECID   WORKCLASSID QTYWORK LOADLINEREFRECID    ORDERNUM    LOADID  SHIPMENTID  ISANCHORED  SKIPPED ACTUALTIME  AVAILPHYSICAL   CONTAINERID ESTIMATEDTIME   FEFOBATCHID LOCATEDLPID REPLENDEMAND    SORTCODE    WORKCLOSEDUTCDATETIME   WORKCLOSEDUTCDATETIMETZID   WORKINPROCESSUTCDATETIME    WORKINPROCESSUTCDATETIMETZID    ZONEID  MODIFIEDDATETIME    MODIFIEDBY  DATAAREAID  RECVERSION  PARTITION   RECID   EXTRAINVENTHANDLINGQTY  CREATEDDATETIME CREATEDBY
WK-000458451    1.0000000000000000  4   1   25-15-4-2   25177222002422  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.0000000000000000  ea  oveta.solo  0   Lot-008210899       0   1   0   SO PICK 1.0000000000000000  5638124347  DUS1-SO-000000284737    LD-000171638    SH-000144368    0   0   23.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   228420  2018-05-08 00:13:59.000 37001   2018-05-08 00:13:36.000 37001   AISLE25 2018-05-08 00:13:59.000 ovet.sol    dus1    1068767787  5637144576  5638710362  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-07 14:26:22.000 $C9DC
WK-000458451    2.0000000000000000  4   2   P1  25177222002422  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.0000000000000000  ea  oveta.solo  0   Lot-008210899       0   1   5637146259  SO PICK 1.0000000000000000  0           SH-000144368    0   0   25.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-08 00:14:24.000 37001   2018-05-08 00:13:59.000 37001       2018-05-08 00:14:24.000 ovet.sol    dus1    516812179   5637144576  5638710361  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-07 14:26:22.000 $C9DC
WK-000465259    1.0000000000000000  4   1   43-52-1-1   21181164962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  80.0000000000000000 ea  lacannin.r  0   Lot-008318480       0   1   0   SO PICK 80.0000000000000000 5638121693  DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   571.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   315780  2018-05-11 19:20:43.000 37001   2018-05-11 19:11:12.000 37001   AISLE43 2018-05-11 19:20:43.000 laca.riz    dus1    1018644541  5637144576  5638731713  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465259    2.0000000000000000  4   2   L1  21181164962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  80.0000000000000000 ea  lacannin.r  0           0   0   5637146149  SO PICK 80.0000000000000000 0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   78.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-11 19:22:02.000 37001   2018-05-11 19:20:44.000 37001       2018-05-11 19:22:02.000 laca.riz    dus1    454248706   5637144576  5638731705  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465259    3.0000000000000000  4   1   L1  21181164962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  80.0000000000000000 ea  willisee.s  1           0   0   5637146150  STAGE   80.0000000000000000 0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   18.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 11:14:42.000 37001   2018-05-14 11:14:24.000 37001       2018-05-14 11:14:42.000 will.sma    dus1    481987558   5637144576  5638731706  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465259    4.0000000000000000  4   2   S1  21181164962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  80.0000000000000000 ea  willisee.s  0           0   0   5637146151  STAGE   80.0000000000000000 0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   5.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 11:14:47.000 37001   2018-05-14 11:14:42.000 37001       2018-05-14 11:14:47.000 will.sma    dus1    2056919670  5637144576  5638731707  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465259    5.0000000000000000  4   1   S1  21181164962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  80.0000000000000000 ea  willisee.s  1           0   0   5637146152  PACKING 80.0000000000000000 0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   12.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 11:15:08.000 37001   2018-05-14 11:14:56.000 37001       2018-05-14 11:15:08.000 will.sma    dus1    1702601158  5637144576  5638731708  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465259    6.0000000000000000  4   2   P1  21181164962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  80.0000000000000000 ea  willisee.s  0           0   1   5637146153  PACKING 80.0000000000000000 0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   5.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 11:15:13.000 37001   2018-05-14 11:15:08.000 37001       2018-05-14 11:15:13.000 will.sma    dus1    1337585537  5637144576  5638731709  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465306    1.0000000000000000  4   1   37-35-3-2   21198244962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  60.0000000000000000 ea  lacannin.r  0   Lot-008317719       0   1   0   SO PICK 60.0000000000000000 5638121692  DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   163.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   286810  2018-05-11 17:56:26.000 37001   2018-05-11 17:53:43.000 37001   AISLE37 2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz    dus1    1000251389  5637144576  5638731710  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465306    2.0000000000000000  4   1   52-62-1-2   21198244962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  65.0000000000000000 ea  lacannin.r  0   Lot-008317719       0   1   0   SO PICK 65.0000000000000000 5638121692  DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   12.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   357550  2018-05-11 18:07:29.000 37001   2018-05-11 18:07:17.000 37001   AISLE52 2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz    dus1    247111420   5637144576  5638731714  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465306    3.0000000000000000  4   1   54-10-1-2   21198244962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  95.0000000000000000 ea  lacannin.r  0   Lot-008317719       0   1   0   SO PICK 95.0000000000000000 5638121692  DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   1513.0000000000000000   0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   358360  2018-05-11 18:32:42.000 37001   2018-05-11 18:07:29.000 37001   AISLE54 2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz    dus1    2030720723  5637144576  5638731715  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465306    4.0000000000000000  4   2   L1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  220.0000000000000000        lacannin.r  0           0   0   5637146149  SO PICK 220.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   5.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-11 18:37:07.000 37001   2018-05-11 18:37:02.000 37001       2018-05-11 18:37:07.000 laca.riz    dus1    1157555216  5637144576  5638728362  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz
WK-000465306    5.0000000000000000  4   1   L1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  220.0000000000000000        Patrice.sa  1           0   0   5637146150  STAGE   220.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   2.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:57:08.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:57:06.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:57:08.000 patr.san    dus1    537033034   5637144576  5638728363  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz
WK-000465306    6.0000000000000000  4   2   S1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  220.0000000000000000        Patrice.sa  0           0   0   5637146151  STAGE   220.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   2.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:57:10.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:57:08.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:57:10.000 patr.san    dus1    1001369257  5637144576  5638728364  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz
WK-000465306    7.0000000000000000  4   1   S1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  220.0000000000000000        Patrice.sa  1           0   0   5637146152  PACKING 220.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   7.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:57:22.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:57:15.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:57:22.000 patr.san    dus1    2001546561  5637144576  5638728365  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz
WK-000465306    8.0000000000000000  4   2   P1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  220.0000000000000000        Patrice.sa  0           0   1   5637146153  PACKING 220.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   3.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:57:25.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:57:22.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:57:25.000 patr.san    dus1    389190161   5637144576  5638728366  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 18:37:01.000 laca.riz
WK-000465775    1.0000000000000000  4   1   38-21-5-1   21177264962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  123.0000000000000000    ea  lacannin.r  0   Lot-008318481       0   1   0   SO PICK 123.0000000000000000    5638121694  DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   108.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   290490  2018-05-11 18:38:55.000 37001   2018-05-11 18:37:07.000 37001   AISLE38 2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 laca.riz    dus1    510896050   5637144576  5638731711  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465775    2.0000000000000000  4   1   38-33-1-2   21177264962430  DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  77.0000000000000000 ea  lacannin.r  0   Lot-008318481       0   1   0   SO PICK 77.0000000000000000 5638121694  DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   474.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   291240  2018-05-11 19:01:31.000 37001   2018-05-11 18:53:37.000 37001   AISLE38 2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 laca.riz    dus1    1959286310  5637144576  5638731712  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 14:37:32.000 $C9DC
WK-000465775    3.0000000000000000  4   2   L1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  200.0000000000000000    ea  lacannin.r  0           0   0   5637146149  SO PICK 200.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   4.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-11 19:01:39.000 37001   2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 37001       2018-05-11 19:01:39.000 laca.riz    dus1    1816505295  5637144576  5638728370  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 laca.riz
WK-000465775    4.0000000000000000  4   1   L1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  200.0000000000000000    ea  Patrice.sa  1           0   0   5637146150  STAGE   200.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   3.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:56:46.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:56:43.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:56:46.000 patr.san    dus1    947174261   5637144576  5638728371  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 laca.riz
WK-000465775    5.0000000000000000  4   2   S1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  200.0000000000000000    ea  Patrice.sa  0           0   0   5637146151  STAGE   200.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   2.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:56:48.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:56:46.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:56:48.000 patr.san    dus1    1418466683  5637144576  5638728372  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 laca.riz
WK-000465775    6.0000000000000000  4   1   S1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  200.0000000000000000    ea  Patrice.sa  1           0   0   5637146152  PACKING 200.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   4.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:56:58.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:56:54.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:56:58.000 patr.san    dus1    603075108   5637144576  5638728373  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 laca.riz
WK-000465775    7.0000000000000000  4   2   P1      DUS1-000021 0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  200.0000000000000000    ea  Patrice.sa  0           0   1   5637146153  PACKING 200.0000000000000000    0   DUS1-SO-000000288083    LD-000173968    SH-000146504    0   0   2.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000      0.0000000000000000          0   0   2018-05-14 15:57:00.000 37001   2018-05-14 15:56:58.000 37001       2018-05-14 15:57:00.000 patr.san    dus1    1082386301  5637144576  5638728374  0.0000000000000000  2018-05-11 19:01:35.000 laca.riz
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I see you are using the same field workclosedutcdatetime to deduce the start and date of a session. If there is no distinction, how can you know when employees jump tasks as you say in 1b? Can you maybe post example data from your `whsworkline` table?

Comment: Hey Jarl, I appreciate the response. I can definitely post some data from that table. And youre right there is no distinction which sucks but I guess what Id really need to do is sum the total of the time per work. Youll see when I post the data but a shipment can have many works to it but we actually ship by shipment, not work. Give me just a few minutes to post some of that data. Thanks again.